# Finding a button click in a Particular tablerow(both Tablwrow and button are dynamically created) Android

Tags: android, button, dynamic, classcastexception

I am trying to make a scheduler app in android. I have a tablelayout. and I am creating tablerows dynamically for every contact added to the weekly schedule. In every TableRow I am adding 6 buttons.
For every button click I have to set some text on the button.
Now I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.Button` .

Here is my piece of code where I am getting error. 
Please note I am getting this error randomly for any button clicked. Sometimes I get this error for 2nd row  and sometimes 3rd row. For all other buttons clicked I am the code i working perfectly fine. I am wondering If I am having same code for button click event , then why I am getting this error for some rows only.

```
    final Button[] btn = new Button[6];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        btn[i] = new Button(this);
        index = i + 1;

        btn[i].setId(index);
        // btn[i].setTag("a"+index);
        // btn[i].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
        // R.drawable.textback));

        btn[i].getBackground().setColorFilter(
                new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFAA0000));

        row.addView(btn[i]);

        btn[i].setText("  ");

        btn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // Button b=(Button)findViewById(v.getId());
                // b.setText(option);

                noOfTimesCalled = 0;
                noOfTimesCalled1 = 0;
                // your desired functionality
                final CharSequence[] items = { "Time Picker", "Sick Leave",
                        "Vacation", "Others" };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                // builder.setView(v);

                builder.setTitle("Select An Option");
                builder.setItems(items,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int item) {

                                switch (item) {

                                case 0:

                                    option.delete(0, option.length());
                                    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar
                                            .getInstance();
                                    int hour = mcurrentTime
                                            .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                    int minute = mcurrentTime
                                            .get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker1;

                                    mTimePicker1 = new TimePickerDialog(
                                            MainActivity.this,
                                            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onTimeSet(
                                                        TimePicker timePicker,
                                                        int selectedHour,
                                                        int selectedMinute) {
                                                    if (noOfTimesCalled == 0) {
                                                        if (selectedHour > 12) {
                                                            int hourtime = selectedHour - 12;
                                                            option.append(hourtime
                                                                    + ":"
                                                                    + selectedMinute
                                                                    + "PM");
                                                            TableRow tr = (TableRow) v
                                                                    .getParent();
                                                            // TableRow
                                                            // tr=(TableRow)findViewById(rowcount);

                                                            Button b = (Button) tr
                                                                    .findViewById(v
                                                                            .getId());
                                                            b.setTextSize(12);
                                                            b.setText(option);

                                                        } else {
                                                            option.append(selectedHour
                                                                    + ":"
                                                                    + selectedMinute
                                                                    + "AM");
                                                            TableRow tr = (TableRow) v
                                                                    .getParent();
                                                            // TableRow
                                                            // tr=(TableRow)findViewById(rowcount);
                                                            Button b = (Button) tr
                                                                    .findViewById(v
                                                                            .getId());
                                                            b.setTextSize(12);
                                                            b.setText(option);
                                                        }

                                                    }
                                                    noOfTimesCalled++;
                                                }
                                            }, hour, minute, false);
                                    mTimePicker1
                                            .setTitle("Select Time: To");

                                    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(
                                            MainActivity.this,
                                            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onTimeSet(
                                                        TimePicker timePicker,
                                                        int selectedHour,
                                                        int selectedMinute) {
                                                    if (noOfTimesCalled1 == 0) {
                                                        if (selectedHour > 12) {
                                                            int hourtime = selectedHour - 12;
                                                            option.append(hourtime
                                                                    + ":"
                                                                    + selectedMinute
                                                                    + "PM"
                                                                    + "-");

                                                        } else
                                                            option.append(selectedHour
                                                                    + ":"
                                                                    + selectedMinute
                                                                    + "AM"
                                                                    + "-");
                                                    }
                                                    noOfTimesCalled1++;
                                                }
                                            }, hour, minute, false);
                                    mTimePicker
                                            .setTitle("Select Time: From");

                                    mTimePicker1.show();
                                    mTimePicker.show();
                                    break;

                                case 1:

                                    option.delete(0, option.length());
                                    option.append("Sick Leave");

                                    TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent();

                                    Button b = (Button) tr.findViewById(v
                                            .getId());
                                    b.setTextSize(12);
                                    b.getBackground()
                                            .setColorFilter(
                                                    new LightingColorFilter(
                                                            0xFFFFFFFF,
                                                            0x000000FF));
                                    b.setText(option);

                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    option.delete(0, option.length());
                                    option.append("Vacation");
                                    TableRow tr1 = (TableRow) v.getParent();

                                    Button b1 = (Button) tr1.findViewById(v
                                            .getId());
                                    b1.setTextSize(12);
                                    b1.getBackground()
                                            .setColorFilter(
                                                    new LightingColorFilter(
                                                            0x0000FF00,
                                                            0x0000FF00));
                                    b1.setText(option);
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    option.delete(0, option.length());
                                    option.append("Others");
                                    TableRow tr11 = (TableRow) v
                                            .getParent();

                                    Button b11 = (Button) tr11
                                            .findViewById(v.getId());

                                    b11.setTextSize(12);
                                    b11.getBackground()
                                            .setColorFilter(
                                                    new LightingColorFilter(
                                                            0x0000FF00,
                                                            0xFFFF0000));
                                    b11.setText(option);
                                    break;

                                }

                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                // Button b=(Button)findViewById(i);
                // b.setText(option.toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

I am calling a Alert Dialog Box on Button Click and Then I am setting Button Text for Each of the option in Alert Dialog box.

I am getting error on the Following code:

```
Button b11 = (Button) tr11.findViewById(v.getId());
```

[Here][1] is the screen shot of my app.. I am able to set text for some buttons. I am getting error for second row first button this time.

I am stuck with this without any clue. Any help is appreciated.. Thank you,

I changed the Error codes :
TableRow tr = (TableRow) v.getParent();

tr.findViewById(v.getId());

To

Button b = (Button) v;

And My Problem got solved....

Comment: Solved this Problem by some search

Comment: I have put the edited Code .. Please see above in the question